# Conditional Multiple radio buttons to show/hide of Difference content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button, conditional-statements

I want the content to be displayed in proportion to the selection of radio buttons.
For example: If (Place 1) is selected with (monthly), the $ 10 button will be displayed,
Or if (Place 1) is selected with (yearly), the $ 130 button will be displayed.
Or if (Place 3) is selected with (yearly), the $ 150 button will be displayed.
I mean, how can the 8 variable modes for  be displayed separately?
Thank you

```
enter code here



  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input:radio').change(function(){
                if($(this).val() ===  "Place-1" || $(this).val() ===  "monthly"){                                                   
                    $('#btn-place-1-monthly').show(); //show    
                    $('#btn-place-2-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-monthly').hide();           
                    $('#btn-place-1-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-yearly').hide();                    
               }   
                if($(this).val() ===  "Place-2" || $(this).val() ===  "monthly"){       
                    $('#btn-place-1-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-monthly').show(); //show
                    $('#btn-place-3-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-monthly').hide();           
                    $('#btn-place-1-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-yearly').hide();                
                }       
                if($(this).val() ===  "Place-3" || $(this).val() ===  "monthly"){       
                    $('#btn-place-1-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-monthly').show(); //show    
                    $('#btn-place-4-monthly').hide();           
                    $('#btn-place-1-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-yearly').hide();                            
                }
                if($(this).val() ===  "Place-4" || $(this).val() ===  "monthly"){
                    $('#btn-place-1-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-monthly').show(); //show            
                    $('#btn-place-1-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-yearly').hide();                    
                }
                if($(this).val() ===  "Place-1" || $(this).val() ===  "yearly"){        
                    $('#btn-place-1-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-monthly').hide();           
                    $('#btn-place-1-yearly').show(); //show
                    $('#btn-place-2-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-yearly').hide();    
                }
                if($(this).val() ===  "Place-2" || $(this).val() ===  "yearly"){        
                    $('#btn-place-1-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-monthly').hide();           
                    $('#btn-place-1-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-yearly').show(); //show
                    $('#btn-place-3-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-yearly').hide();    
                }
                if($(this).val() ===  "Place-3" || $(this).val() ===  "yearly"){
                    $('#btn-place-1-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-1-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-yearly').show(); //show
                    $('#btn-place-4-yearly').hide();                    
                }
                if($(this).val() ===  "Place-4" || $(this).val() ===  "yearly"){        
                    $('#btn-place-1-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-monthly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-monthly').hide();           
                    $('#btn-place-1-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-2-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-3-yearly').hide();
                    $('#btn-place-4-yearly').show(); //show         
                }           
                });     
          });
        </script>

enter code here



<html>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="pricing-toggle-container">
        <div class="toggle-container">
          <div class="switch-toggle well">            
            <input id="Place-1" name="place" type="radio" value="Place-1" checked>
            <label for="Place-1">Place 1</label>            
            <input id="Place-2" name="place" type="radio" value="Place-2">
            <label for="Place-2">Place 2</label>            
            <input id="Place-3" name="place" type="radio" value="Place-3">
            <label for="Place-3">Place 3</label>            
            <input id="Place-4" name="place" type="radio" value="Place-4">
            <label for="Place-4">Place 4</label>            
            <a class="btn btn-primary"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle-container">
          <div class="switch-toggle well">            
            <input id="monthly" name="time" type="radio" value="monthly" checked>
            <label for="monthly">1 month</label>            
            <input id="yearly" name="time" type="radio" value="yearly">
            <label for="yearly">12 months</label>           
            <a class="btn btn-primary"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="pricing-container">               
<a id="btn-place-1-monthly" href="#" class="btn-price">$10</a>
<a id="btn-place-2-monthly" href="#" class="btn-price">$20</a>
<a id="btn-place-3-monthly" href="#" class="btn-price">$30</a>
<a id="btn-place-4-monthly" href="#" class="btn-price">$40</a>
<a id="btn-place-1-yearly" href="#" class="btn-price">$130</a>
<a id="btn-place-2-yearly" href="#" class="btn-price">$140</a>
<a id="btn-place-3-yearly" href="#" class="btn-price">$150</a>
<a id="btn-place-4-yearly" href="#" class="btn-price">$160</a>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Thank you so much "FSodic",
Your code works very well for tag a>, but if I want to add h1, h3, h5, h6 tags, how do I change them?
for example:

```html
<h1 id="place-1-monthly" class="price">$10</h1>
<h1 id="place-2-monthly" class="price">$20</h1>
<h1 id="place-3-monthly" class="price">$30</h1>
<h1 id="place-4-monthly" class="price">$40</h1>     
<h1 id="place-1-yearly" class="price">$130</h1>
<h1 id="place-2-yearly" class="price">$140</h1>
<h1 id="place-3-yearly" class="price">$150</h1>
<h1 id="place-4-yearly" class="price">$160</h1>
```

Comment: please could you close the question by validating the right answer for you .. thanks fo all helpers

Answer (score 1):

this does the job, i have added initial values:

```js
var place='place-1';
var lapse='monthly';
setLinks();
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).attr('id').includes('Place')){
       place = $(this).attr('id').toLowerCase();
    }else if ($(this).attr('id').includes('ly')){
       lapse = $(this).attr('id');
    }
    setLinks()                
});

function setLinks(){
    if(place != '' && lapse != ''){
      $('a[id^=btn-]').hide();
      $('#btn-' + place + '-' + lapse).show();
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
</script>
<html>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="pricing-toggle-container">
        <div class="toggle-container">
          <div class="switch-toggle well">            
            <input id="Place-1" name="place" type="radio" value="Place-1" checked>
            <label for="Place-1">Place 1</label>            
            <input id="Place-2" name="place" type="radio" value="Place-2">
            <label for="Place-2">Place 2</label>            
            <input id="Place-3" name="place" type="radio" value="Place-3">
            <label for="Place-3">Place 3</label>            
            <input id="Place-4" name="place" type="radio" value="Place-4">
            <label for="Place-4">Place 4</label>            
            <a class="btn btn-primary"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle-container">
          <div class="switch-toggle well">            
            <input id="monthly" name="time" type="radio" value="monthly" checked>
            <label for="monthly">1 month</label>            
            <input id="yearly" name="time" type="radio" value="yearly">
            <label for="yearly">12 months</label>           
            <a class="btn btn-primary"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="pricing-container">               
<a id="btn-place-1-monthly" href="#" class="btn-price">$10</a>
<a id="btn-place-2-monthly" href="#" class="btn-price">$20</a>
<a id="btn-place-3-monthly" href="#" class="btn-price">$30</a>
<a id="btn-place-4-monthly" href="#" class="btn-price">$40</a>
<a id="btn-place-1-yearly" href="#" class="btn-price">$130</a>
<a id="btn-place-2-yearly" href="#" class="btn-price">$140</a>
<a id="btn-place-3-yearly" href="#" class="btn-price">$150</a>
<a id="btn-place-4-yearly" href="#" class="btn-price">$160</a>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Frenchy, thank you for the answer
But unfortunately it did not work and there is an error.

Comment: Yes, I added parentheses but it does not work

Comment: hum..yes again typo with attrid instead attr.. the snippet is okay!!

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, if I add a title and description with h1,h3...tags , will they change like buttons?
Or how do I change the tags?

Comment: please dont change the question because the answer has no sense . i suggest you to close the question (by validating it) and ask new question to avoid confusion (please rewrite your inital problem)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
yourFunction();
  $('input:radio').change(function(){
    yourFunction();
  });
});
function yourFunction(){
  var a = $('input[name="place"]:checked').val().toLowerCase(), b = $('input[name=time]:checked').val().toLowerCase();
  $('a.btn-price').hide(); //Hide all btn price
  $('a.btn-price#btn-'+a+'-'+b).show();
}
</script>
```

I see your btn class using lowercase, so it just transform the value.
`yourFunction();` will exec after the page ready and after the input (time and place) changed

Comment: Thank you so much "FSodic", Your code works very well.

Comment: Can you help me to change the h1,h3... tags in the example above?

Comment: Ya, just follow my example on `setLinks()`
`$('h1[id^=btn-]').hide(); // here
$('#btn-' + place + '-' + lapse).show();`